# Angularjs2 Two ways databinding with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I'm starting with angularjs2. I want to implement two ways databinding with angularjs2, php and mysql. I don't really know if it's possible, I can't figure it out.

I return Json data but I got an error: ***SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0***

I would like to implement the 2 ways databinding so that when there is a change in database, an update occurs on client side. I don't want to use Ajax to send too much request to database. Is there a way to do that ? I head about Websocket but I'm lost.

If it's not possible, how to do that in php without framework ? Thanks in advance.

Here my code:

**app.component file**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

import {spcService} from './spc.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <spc_match></spc_match>
    {{contour}}   

    <ul>
        <li  *ngFor ="#elt of element">
            {{ elt.Nom_etud }}

        </li>
    </ul> 
    `,

    providers: [spcService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    element: any[];
    contour ="Test angular"; 

    constructor (private _spcService: spcService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
          this._spcService.getPost()
         .subscribe(
         element => this.element = element,
         spcs => console.log(spcs),
             );
    }
 }
```

**spc.service.ts file**

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


//import {Elements} from './elements';

@Injectable()

export class spcService{
   // getMatchlist(): string[]{
   //     return ["match1","match2","match3"];
   // }

 // private _ulr ="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
 private _ulr ="http://localhost:3000/server/student_liste.php";
  //private _ulr ="server/student_liste.php";
   constructor( private _http : Http){}

   getPost(){
      return this._http.get(this._ulr)
       .map( res =>res.json())
      // .map( res  =><Element[]> res.json())
   }
}
```

**php script to load data from server**

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 

function get_student_list() {
    $result_trans =array();
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Abidjan');
$connect=new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test_angular')or die('erreur de connexion a la db');
$connect->set_charset('utf8');

  $liste_eleves='SELECT *  FROM eleves';

    $stmtfind_race= $connect->stmt_init();
    $stmtfind_race->prepare($liste_eleves) ;
    $stmtfind_race->bind_result($ident,$nom,$prenom,$age);
    $stmtfind_race->execute();
    $stmtfind_race->store_result();
    $numRows = $stmtfind_race->num_rows;
     while ( $stmtfind_race->fetch()) {
      # code...
      $result_trans [] = array("id_etud"=>$ident,"Nom_etud" => $nom,"Prenom" => $prenom, "Age"=> $age);
    }
    return  $result_trans;
}

    $value = get_student_list(); 

echo json_encode($value,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ;
?>
```

Comment: Your error indicates that there is malformed JSON in the response. Error most likely in your script.

Comment: But my php script returns a correct json. I don't know why this error ?

Comment: Well, it  seems it is not valid json. In your `getPost`-method try to map the data and see how it looks like: `.map((res: Response) => { console.log('res', res); })`

Comment: Your code seems to return the entire script instead of the json.

Comment: That's the response??